# Execute some functions of ethereum smart contract using ONLY my website

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I want user to be able to execute some functions of my Ethereum smart contract using ONLY my website via MetaMask. There should be no way to execute functions *not* using my website. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, it would look like this: user from your website sends request via Metamask to your backend, which encrypts a user's request via a secret key (lets name it "hash") and send it with the body request to your smart-contract (so `sendToContract({hash, body})`). After that, the smart-contract encrypts the body via the secret key (lets name it "hash2") and compares "hash2" with "hash"

So, smart-contracts needs to store a secret key, [but it's impossible to store secret data in a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49832/storing-secret-in-smart-contract).

Yeah, you can try to hide this secret key, but eventually, you cannot have a 100% guarantee that only your backend and smart-contract know the secret key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not solve my problem "No way to execute functions not using my website". My question is about security.

Comment: could you clarify a little bit more, I didn't get it. "No way to execute functions not using my website"

Comment: Users have to call functions of smart contract ONLY from my website. It is not possible for users to call functions of smart contract from where else except my website